# Jenkins creating workspace@2 in nonconcurrent build

Tags: jenkins

I am using a Github Organization Job which has two repos that I am building. In each job when the branch runs it will checkout the repo to get the Jenkinsfile, then checkout again in workspace@2. This represents issues in the Jenksinfile when it is looking for build artifacts at the end of the build, such as code coverage metrics, because sometimes it is in workspace other times workspace@2. Is there a way to tell Jenkins to use the same workspace from the original checkout? Why is it attempting to create a second workspace rather than use the original?

I have upgraded to the latests plugins which didn't fix it. I have tried cleaning the workspace and deleting the directory, but neither of those have resolved it either. I read somewhere online that it may be envionment variables so I tried changing those to params and didn't fix it either.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'node'
    }
    environment {
        TEMP_VAR = '/tmp/installs'
        MV_TEMP_VAR = '/root/temps')
    }
    options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent { 
                docker {
                    image 'java-image:latest'
                    args '-u root:root'
                } 
            }
            steps { 
                sh 'gradle clean build jacocoTestReport jacocoTestCoverageVerification' 
            }
        }
        stage('Send Coverage to Github') {
                publishCoverageGithub(filepath:"./build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml", coverageXmlType: 'jacoco')
            }
        }
        stage('Report Coverage to Jenkins Job') {
            steps {
                publishCoverage adapters: [jacocoAdapter("./build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml")], sourceFileResolver: sourceFiles('STORE_LAST_BUILD')
            }
        }
    }
}
```